# Find records where at least one fulfills a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm looking to find some records from Mongo where they all fulfill some condition and that at least one of them fulfills a second, separate, condition.

**Example:**

Say records have `counter` & `isHandled` parameters (`Number` & `Boolean` respectfully).
I'd like to find all records where `counter >= 100` and that **at least** one of the records that fulfill the first requirement also has `isHandled` set to `false`.

Say I have these records:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "counter": 50,
    "isHandled": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "counter": 50,
    "isHandled": true
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "counter": 100,
    "isHandled": true
  },
  {
    "_id": "4",
    "counter": 100,
    "isHandled": true
  },
  {
    "_id": "5",
    "counter": 120,
    "isHandled": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "6",
    "counter": 100,
    "isHandled": true
  }
]
```

And also `threshold = 100`. My query should return the records with `_id`  `"3", "4", "5" & "6"`. However, if record `"5"` was not there, then no record should be returned. The reason is that since all of the records that satisfy the first condition (`counter`), none satisfy the second condition.

My first part might be `{ counter: { $gte: threshold } }`.

Any idea how I can achieve this? Some sort of pipeline?

Comment: @ray - I'v edited the question itself, but also clarifying here: I need to have one of the documents that satisfies `counter >= 100` to also have `isHandled` set to `false`. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$match` with counter : {$gte: threshold}
2. `$setWindowFields` to compute `$rank` for `isHandled` field. The trick here is if all records are true, they will all share the rank: 1. If some documents are false, the false documents will have rank: 1 and true documents will have rank: 2
3. `$match` all records by a `$or` condition on `isHandled: false` or `rank: 2`( that means they are true documents, but there exists some false documents to make it having rank 2)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      counter: {
        $gte: 100
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        "isHandled": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          $denseRank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$isHandled",
              false
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$rank",
              2
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "rank"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IKdHRptC0aK)

EDIT: thanks for @Noel 's comment. Changed to use `$denseRank` from `$rank`

Comment: That's actually a very interesting way to deal with this. Works very nicely. Thanks

Comment: I think the ranking function should be `$denseRank`.  If there are more than one false documents, it doesn't return the other true documents. https://mongoplayground.net/p/CGnDaVv2v0a

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
const threshold = 100;

db.collection.find({ 
  $and: [
    { counter: { $gte: threshold } }, 
    { 
      $or: [
        { isHandled: false }, 
        { isHandled: { $exists: false } }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think this will help me. The threshold will be satisfied, true, but this query will give me all records where `isHandled` is `false` (the case where it doesn't exist is 1. something shouldn't occur - 2. Doesn't help us.